# How to lockdown routing to public and private parts, that's behind a GCP load balancer

Tags: google-cloud-platform, load-balancing

I have a static JS application hosted in a Gcloud storage bucket and uses a Gcloud CDN. This set up is behind a single HTTPS load balancer.

I have two entry points to the app, namely **/endpoint1**, **/endpoint2**. Right now both the end points are publicly accessible. Where as, only **/endpoint1** has to be public. I want to make **/endpoint2** a private endpoint and only accessible from a certain space, say 10.0.0.0/24.

Is it possible to achieve this? If not, please suggest an other way around.

Answer (score 0):

At this time your objectives are not possible without changing services.

Your objectives:

1. /endpoint1 is public
2. /endpoint2 is accessible from a CIDR block.

Note: 10.0.0.0/24 is a private IP block. Only public IP addresses reach the cloud.

Cloud Storage does not offer firewall type rules to control access. Buckets/objects are either public or controlled by IAM identity-based access and OAuth access tokens containing IAM roles/permissions.

You will need to move your app to a service that offers compute abilities so that you can implement your access control objectives. Options include Compute Engine, Cloud Run, Firebase, App Engine Standard, or App Engine Flexible.

Note: you can continue to host your public static files on Cloud Storage and also with your combination of HTTP Load Balancer plus CDN plus Cloud Storage. You might need to change the DNS endpoint so that your app can be hosted from multiple combined services.

**Advanced Solution:**

Leave /endpoint1 hosted by LB + CDN + Cloud Storage. Create a compute service from the list above to host /endpoint2. Add a backend to the load balancer that points to the compute service. Create a URL Map to forward traffic to the correct backend. Now you can add Cloud Armor to control access to /endpoint2.

**Simple Solution:**

If your site is low traffic and/or does not have large storage requirements, move your app to Cloud Run. Very low cost, easy to implement and manage plus autoscaling. Put access control in your application logic.

Comment: Thanks for a clear explanation. I moved my app to cloud run. Now that I think about it, how about I create an api gateway? Is that a good architecture?

Comment: Yes, you set up Cloud Run as an API Gateway backend. However, to protect `/endpont2`, you would then need to implement authorization (OAuth). Cloud Run already has that feature.